# three.js object dynamic change with LOD animation

Tags: three.js

I made a website with three.js for 3d work.

It's concept is universe that has so many texts.

There is 2 things I have to implement.

First. Object is star when distance between camera and object is far.

Second. Object is Text when distance between camera and object is close.

So, I implement it with [LOD](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/LOD).

Everything works fine.

But, star <-> text change trainsition is so rough.

I want to insert smooth change transition(animation) into it.

So I read a docs, sadly, there is any properties about it.

Is it possible to insert animation into LOD?

or any possible soulution about this?

**[Source code]**

```js
// VARIABLES
let clock, camera, scene, renderer, mixer;

var myElement = document.getElementById("threejs");
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
const clicked = new THREE.Vector2();
const target = new THREE.Vector2();
const windowHalf = new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 );
const moveState = {forward: 0, back: 0};
var isMobile = false;
var textCount = 200;

checkMobile()
init();

function init() { 
  // CAMERA
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2100 );
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 1200;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xf05fa6, 300, 400);

  clock = new THREE.Clock();

 // HELPER
  
  const gridHelper = new THREE.PolarGridHelper( 8, 16 );
  scene.add( gridHelper );

  // LIGHT
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.2 );
  scene.add( ambientLight );

  const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
  directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, - 1 );
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  // CONTROLS
  if(isMobile) {
    var controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
    console.log('isMobile true');
  } else {
    console.log('isMobile false');
  }
  
  // ADD MESH
  var group = new THREE.Group();
  var size = ( isMobile ? 2 : 4 );
  var starsLights = new THREE.Group();

  for ( let i = 0; i < textCount; i ++ ) {
    var lod = new THREE.LOD();
    // Star
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.3, 16, 16);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
    var star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    // Text
    let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite({
      textSize: size,
      redrawInterval: 250,
      texture: {
        text: 'TEST TEST TEST',
        fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
      },
      material: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    });
    // Star Light
    var velX = (Math.random() + 0.1) * 0.1 * (Math.random()<0.5?-1:1);
    var velY = (Math.random() + 0.1) * 0.1 * (Math.random()<0.5?-1:1);
    star.vel = new THREE.Vector2(velX, velY);
    var starLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x000000, 0.8, 3);
    starLight.position.copy(star.position);
    starLight.position.y += 0.5;
    starsLights.add(starLight);
    // Add
    lod.addLevel(sprite, 1);
    lod.addLevel(star, 200);
    lod.position.x = Math.random() * 180-100;
    lod.position.y = Math.random() * 180-100;
    lod.position.z = Math.random() * 1000-40;
    group.add(lod);
//    group.add(starsLights);
  }
  scene.add(group);
  scene.add(starLight);

  // Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.getElementById("universe").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Event handler
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false);
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);


  function animate() {
    target.x = ( 1 - mouse.x ) * 0.002;
    target.y = ( 1 - mouse.y ) * 0.002;
    camera.rotation.x += 0.05 * ( target.y - camera.rotation.x );
    camera.rotation.y += 0.05 * ( target.x - camera.rotation.y );

    if(isMobile) {
      controls.update();
    }
    // Object change related to distance
    group.children.forEach(function(child) {
      child.update(camera);
      var distance = camera.position.distanceTo(child.position);
      var opacity = -1 / 400 * distance + 1;
      if (opacity < 0) {
        opacity = 0;
      }
      child.getObjectForDistance(distance).material.opacity = opacity;
    })
    // Render
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render(scene, camera);
  }
  
  animate();
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function onMouseWheel(event) {
  if(camera.position.z > 100) {
    event.preventDefault();
    camera.position.z -= event.deltaY * 0.2;
  } else {

  }
}

function render() {
  const delta = clock.getDelta();
  if ( mixer !== undefined ) mixer.update( delta );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onTransitionEnd( event ) {
  console.log("Loading Complete");
  event.target.remove();
}

// Exist functions
function checkMobile() {
  var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent;

  if (UserAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|Android|Windows CE|BlackBerry|Symbian|Windows Phone|webOS|Opera Mini|Opera Mobi|POLARIS|IEMobile|lgtelecom|nokia|SonyEricsson/i) != null || UserAgent.match(/LG|SAMSUNG|Samsung/) != null) {
      isMobile = true;
  } else {
      isMobile = false;
  }
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = ( (event.clientX/2) - (windowHalf.x/2) );
  mouse.y = ( (event.clientY/2) - (windowHalf.y/2) );
  clicked.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  clicked.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function onResize(event) {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  
  windowHalf.set( width / 2, height / 2 );
 
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( width, height );
}

function onContextMenu(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
/*  background: #11e8bb;  Old browsers */
/*  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb 0%, #8200c9 100%);  FF3.6-15 */
/*  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #11e8bb 0%,#8200c9 100%);  Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
/*  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #11e8bb 0%,#8200c9 100%);  W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #ed1654, #f61e6c, #f76098);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#11e8bb', endColorstr='#8200c9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#threejs {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}
/* Header Left */
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
.header-left img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
}
/* Header Right */
.header-right {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
.header-right a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.header-right a:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
/* Main Company */
.down-btn {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.down-btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Section */
section {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--  <script src="three.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.texttexture"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three.textsprite"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-left">
      <a href="#">MAIN</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
      <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section id="universe"></section>
  <script src="src.js"></script>
  <section id="section">
    SECTION
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`THREE.LOD` can't do what you are looking for. But it's not that hard to write a custom LOD class that performs a smooth alpha blending between two levels. The advantage of this approach is that it is perceived as more continuous than discrete LODs. However, since two objects are rendered during the transition, it's computationally a bit more expensive.

The following fiddle illustrates this approach (I'm sure it's possible to implement this more elegant but it's at least a starting point^^): https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/14585/

When creating a LOD object, you can adjust a threshold value that defines the extent of the transition.

```
 const lod = new LOD();
 lod.threshold = 250;
```

Comment: You mean that just set `threshold` property to `lod`?

Comment: No, the `threshold` property is a scalar property that defines how long the distance is in which the transition between two LODs happens.